# DRF, Djongo and log4mongo

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have setup log4mogo to capture django logs and this is working and putting all the logs into the database correctly.

I would like to expose these as part of the drf api and have tried to setup djongo as the orm for this access to the mongo db, but for some reason I get nothing back, I would like to know if someone has any ideas on this. In terms of error, I don't get one I get back an empty dict. So it would seem as the query is coming back with nothing, but there is entries in the db. I am lost as to a direction to go in so any thoughts would be welcome.

Model:

```
import djongo.models


class Logs(djongo.models.Model):

    _id = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    thread = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    level = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    timestamp = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    threadName = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    module = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    loggerName = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    lineNumber = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    message = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    fileName = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
    method = djongo.models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

View:

```
class UserViewSet(rest_framework.viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    queryset = logger_api.models.Logs.objects.using('logging_api').all()
    serializer_class = logger_api.serializers.LogSerializer
```

settings:

```
DATABASES = {
        'logging_api': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'logging',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': ********************,
                'port': ********************,
                'username': ***********,
                'password': ***********,
                'authSource': *********,
                'ssl': True
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe there's some problem with serialization. Have you tried printing what's on serializer's input?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yeah I have tried to and I just get an empty list, which is why I believe that the query is returning no objects, what I can't confirm from djongo is the collection being queried and the query syntax. as there is for sure documents in the db that would match the all.

Comment: Maybe try simplifying the structure a bit, eg. leave only _id and thread. By the way, you sure you need to specify _id explicitly? That's not common in context of django models.